# Combining 2 Mysql queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I currently running two queries to find one result, I have a good feeling I can combine these two queries into one. I've tried the method below but it's still showing me results that already appear from `access_number` table.

```
$query = "select * FROM `$table`.`access_number` WHERE `active`='1'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  list($dd_inuse) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT `did` FROM `$table`.`customer_dd` WHERE `did`='$row[did]' AND `callerid`='$callerid' LIMIT 1",$db));
  if(!$dd_inuse) {
     $goodone = $row['did'];
     break;
   }
}
```

I tried combining it like this and it's not showing me unique values

```
select `access_number`.`did` from `access_number` 
INNER JOIN `customer_dd` 
WHERE `customer_dd`.`callerid`='$callerid' 
AND `customer_dd`.`did` !=`access_number`.`did` LIMIT 1
```

Bottom line is, I'm trying to find a value in table `access_number` that does not exist in `customer_dd`

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to wrap a while in the results from the first results for the second results.

Comment: i was hoping to just use one query and not do the looping after the first fetch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `left join` and `not null` for this

```
select 
a.access_number from access_number a
left join customer_dd c on c.did = a.did and c.callerid = '$callerid'
where c.did is null
```

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
SELECT `did` FROM `$table`.`customer_dd` 
WHERE `did`='$row[did]' AND `callerid` = '$callerid' LIMIT 1
```

base on you code, i found your table `access_number.did = customer_dd.did`.

so you can try:

```
select `access_number`.`did` from `access_number` 
INNER JOIN `customer_dd` ON `customer_dd`.`did` = `access_number`.`did`
WHERE `customer_dd`.`callerid` = '$callerid' AND `access_number`.`active`='1' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this is the opposite of what I want... I want to find an `access_number` that is not in `customer_dd`